# Select A or B using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{ 
  string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectOne : ISomeInterface
{
  public string Id;
  // Other properties... 
}

public class ObjectTwo : ISomeInterface
{
  public string Id;
  // Other properties...
}
```

And also this:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public List<ObjectOne> ObjectOneCollection;
  public List<ObjectTwo> ObjectTwoCollection;

  public ISomeInterface GetMatching(string key)
  {
    ISomeInterface result;

    result = from ISomeInterface a in ObjectOneCollection
             from ISomeInterface b in ObjectTwoCollection
             where a.Id == key || 
                   b.Id == key
             select new { a, b }; // This is where I'm having trouble.

    return result;
  } 

  // Other methods
}
```

I'm basically trying to select `a` or `b` in the LINQ query whichever is first. How would I go about doing this?

(I know there are many ways to do this such as trying to get `a` first and null-checking, and so on for `b`. That makes for some ugly code. I also know about using `Concat` to combine the two collections.)

Comment: What do you mean by "whichever is first"?

Comment: If you know about using `Concat` for concatting two sequences, why aren't you using it?  It's the correct operation for what you want; `SelectMany` (which you're currently using) is not.

Comment: `I also know about using Concat to combine the two collections.`... and that doesn't apply in my case because...

Comment: "`whichever is first`" `==` `.First()`

Comment: @JustinMorgan Presumably there would only be one result from the two collections. I'm ultimately trying to get that one result.

Comment: @Servy I was looking for an alternative because I was under the impression that `Concat` was an `IList` function. I have since found out that it's `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Cameron Yet you didn't even try it?

Comment: @Servy I have now, and I was able to clean it up quite nicely. The exact situation that I was trying to avoid was eouw0o83hf's response where it has a bunch of types strung throughout the operation.

Comment: @Cameron  Good thing they're all superfluous.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. ReSharper showed me which ones were unneeded and I assumed some would be unnecessary because of the implementation of the interface. Just wasn't sure how it would all connect.

Comment: The end result came out to be `var all = ObjectOneCollection.Concat<ISomeInterface>(ObjectTwoCollection);` which is about the cleanest I can get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to find the first one that matches, and your best bet should just be to `Concat()` the collections and return the first match:

```
ObjectOneCollection.Cast<ISomeInterface>()
  .Concat(ObjectTwoCollection.Cast<ISomeInterface>())
  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == key);
```

Comment: The second cast is redundant, and the first can be avoided by explicitly specifying the generic argument of `Concat`.

Comment: @Servy true. I was trying to illustrate explicitly what's going on so it's easy to follow.

Comment: Having types strung out all was one of the things I was trying to avoid. But I ended up using something very similar to this (without the unnecessary casting and such.)